# java random number generator without arrays

Tags: java, random, duplicates

I am completely new to Java and working on an assignment. I need to generate 6 random numbers within the range of 1 - 49, which is simple. 
However, the complication is that the numbers cannot duplicate. 
The only options I have for conditionals are the while loop, or the if else statements.
Arrays and all other loops are off limits for this assignment.
Could really use some advice regarding logistics of how to apply the options I have. I realize without arrays, and the other loops that I'm going to have a lot of duplicate code but can handle that. I just need some help wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Sets?

Comment: How do you save the already generated numbers?

Comment: Are you required to simply print out the list of numbers? Without an array or a `List` of some sorts, I'm not sure how you'd store the 6 numbers ...

Comment: I do not understand the requirement of not using arrays. Cesare's answer indeed provides a solution without using arrays, but how is six separate variables as used in that answer fundamentally different from using an array? If this is an assignment, it's a strange one.

Comment: We are not using sets yet. I apologize, I forgot to mention that I have stored all six numbers as variables. The requirements for the assignment require that I do not print out the numbers, rather store them for the second part of the assignment which requires comparing the stored numbers to user input. (which will also be interesting without arrays, and the use of only one loop). The assignment is odd, however, the challenge is to produce the intended results without moving ahead in the text, which is where the text covers arrays.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use arrays, or other collections, you can create 6 variables to save your generate numbers.

```
public class Generate6Number {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    int num4 = 0;
    int num5 = 0;
    int num6 = 0;

    int count = 0;

    while (count < 6) {
        int numGen = (int) (Math.random() * 49);

        if (numGen != num1 &&
            numGen != num2 &&
            numGen != num3 &&
            numGen != num4 &&
            numGen != num5) {
            if (num1 == 0)
                num1 = numGen;
            else if (num2 == 0)
                num2 = numGen;
            else if (num3 == 0)
                num3 = numGen;
            else if (num4 == 0)
                num4 = numGen;
            else if (num5 == 0)
                num5 = numGen;
            else 
                num6 = numGen;

            count++;
        }
    }   

    System.out.println("Number 1: " + num1);
    System.out.println("Number 2: " + num2);
    System.out.println("Number 3: " + num3);
    System.out.println("Number 4: " + num4);
    System.out.println("Number 5: " + num5);
    System.out.println("Number 6: " + num6);

}

}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. I have a much messier version using several while loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<>();
Random rand = new Random();

while (values.size() <= 6) {
    int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    values.add(n);
}
System.out.println(values);
```

Comment: 1) code-only answers are discouraged; you should provide an explanation 2) if OP can’t use an array, they probably can’t use a set.

Comment: confirmed, no sets allowed for this one, but thank you for trying. I can still use this example in my next project.

Answer (score 0):

like shuffling a card for first 6

```
public void shuffle() {
    int[] array = new int[49];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // we need first 6 random cards
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * (( array.length - i) + 1));
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.print("[" + array[i] + "]");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: OP specifically said they could not use an `Array`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a rather strange exercise to attempt without arrays. It is possible, but I don't think it is especially instructive for learning Java, as it is more a maths exercise than a programming one.

In order to generate 6 distinct random numbers in the range 1-49, you basically have to decide for each of those 49 numbers whether or not to "pick" it, with the constraint that you will only pick 6 numbers. So, you are looking to identify one of the `choose(49, 6)` possible combinations.

So, you can do it like this:

```
int numToPick = 6;
for (int i = 1; i <= 49; ++i) {
  if (shouldPick(i, numToPick)) {
    System.out.println(i);
    --numToPick;
  }
}
```

(I used a for loop; but you can always rewrite a for loop as a while loop if that's all you can use).

The question is just how to implement that `shouldPick` function: it returns a boolean true to mean that you should pick it, and will print it; or false to mean that you won't.

This is going to be a probabilistic function (i.e
 it's going to use a random number generator), or it won't give you different sets of numbers each time.

The maths to work out the form of that function is quite fun, and the ultimate implementation is pleasingly trivial; but it wouldn't be fun if I gave the answer here.

(But I can assure you that I have implemented it, only changing one line in the above snippet; 2 if you count declaring a random number generator).

Comment: So many good points! I very much wanted to use the for loop but ran into the issue with shouldPick. Essentially there's no way of getting this done without being messy and lengthy in my code, but once it's done I can then move onto assignments using arrays, for and do loops.

Answer (score 0):

You effectively need to take out the already chosen possibility:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int first = rand.nextInt(49) + 1;
int second = rand.nextInt(48) + 1;
int third = rand.nextInt(47) + 1;
int fourth = rand.nextInt(46) + 1;
int fifth = rand.nextInt(45) + 1;
int sixth = rand.nextInt(44) + 1;

if (first <= second) second++;
if (first <= third) third++;
if (first <= fourth) fourth++;
if (first <= fifth) fifth++;
if (first < sixth) sixth++;

if (second <= third) third++;
if (second <= fourth) fourth++;
if (second <= fifth) fifth++;
if (second <= sixth) sixth++;

if (third <= fourth) fourth++;
if (third <= fifth) fifth++;
if (third <= sixth) sixth++;

if (fourth <= fifth) fifth++;
if (fourth <= sixth) sixth++;

if (fifth <= sixth) sixth++;
```

Comment: This is very helpful, and similar to the way I've used while loops in my code, however, I will more than likely utilize the if statements this way when comparing the user input to the 6 saved numbers.

Comment: @NewbieJava It would be very nice to have an array and be able to do this with cycles, but the question excludes that possibility. Is this post answering your question?